# how to create middleware that can access by 1 or more role with laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.5

I have custom middleware like this

[image]

then this is my routes

[image]

I want

```
Route::post('facility', 'FacilityController@store')
        ->name('facility.store')
        ->middleware(['superAdmin', 'admin', 'tenantRelation', 'receptionist']);
```

can be access by these 4 roles, but always fail.

Anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stacking one middleware on top of other, so the request is passed on from one middleware to another and if any failure occur, the request won't be processed further.

You need to create another middleware that would check whether the user falls under any of the given role.

```
php artisan make:middleware RestrictedAccess
```

and in the handle method of the middleware you could do

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $role_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    if (! in_array(auth()->user()->roleId, $role_ids)) {
        abort('403');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and add the middleware to `App\Http\Kernel.php` file's

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'auth.restricted_access' => \App\Http\Middleware\RestrictedAccess::class,
    ...
];
```

then you could modify your route as

```
Route::post('facility', 'FacilityController@store')
        ->name('facility.store')
        ->middleware('auth.restricted_access');
```